# How do you download urls of pdfs online and save it using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pdf

I have an excel file out of which in one of the columns urls are present. These URLs are basically PDF Files. Is there a way to download these PDF files without opening the links using python and save it in a specified folder on your machine?
I can think of a way to open the excel file using `pd.read_excel('excel_name.xlsx', col_name='pdf links')` but I have no idea of downloading the files in a sequential manner.
And even some pdf links are duplicated, in that case how do I ensure to keep only the first reported link? Or for instance, I can use `df.drop_duplicates()`
Here is a sample excel file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuPSs.png
Please help!!

Here's what I've tried:

```
import dload
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_excel('examples.xlsx', sheet_name='Reports and URL')
#print(df['URL'])
df1 = df['URL'].to_numpy()
print(df1)

for urls in df1:
    pdfs = dload.save(urls, 'F:/technophile/proj/')
    print(pdfs)

print('saved!')
```

and this is the error I get `requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.incitecpivot.com.au', port=443)`

**EDIT 2**:- removed for loop and used `dload.save_multi()` still gave the same error.

Comment: why can't you use `requests` to download these files? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question.
It seems simple enough to use an excel lib like xlwings or pandas to read the workbook then take the URL column in as an array, and then just loop & download ( with request or anything you like) & save the file any where you'd like to.

Comment: And for the duplicate URLs, just judge them with [in] like
```
if temp_url in your_url_array:
```

Comment: @Craab will try this one and let you know.

Comment: @Craab getting this error using dload: ``` requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.incitecpivot.com.au', port=443) ``` please check my updated question

Comment: @technophile_3 not sure about this "dload" package but with requests, you can disable ssl verification and bypass the error, not elegant but works.

Comment: @technophile_3 FYI, sample code would be like 
down_res = requests.get(url=your_url, verify=False)

with open("/Users/craab/Desktop/1.pdf", "wb") as code:
    code.write(down_res.content)

print('saved!')
`

Comment: @Craab solved it using dload package. thanks for your pointers